# Phoenix Persistent Builds Issue: Dependencies Recompiling Every Time

Tags: dependencies, elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

When I run mix commands in my project, it seems that Elixir recompiles all the dependencies every single time, making the development process slower than expected. However, I noticed that when I develop the same project within a Docker container, the dependencies are compiled only once, and subsequent mix commands are significantly faster.

I've already tried enabling persistent builds by setting the MIX_ENV environment variable to "dev" and running mix compile --persistent, but this doesn't seem to resolve the issue.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
Set MIX_ENV to "dev" both locally and within the Docker container.
Checked my Elixir version (I'm using the latest stable version).
Cleaned the project using mix clean.
Verified the MIX_ENV variable to ensure it is correctly set.
```

Unfortunately, none of these actions have made a difference, and I'm still facing the same problem. It's puzzling that the behavior is different between my local environment and the Docker container.

Has anyone else experienced a similar issue with Elixir dependencies recompiling every time? I'd greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or tips on how to resolve this situation. Perhaps I'm missing something essential or there's a configuration I need to adjust?

If you've encountered this before or have any ideas to troubleshoot this issue, I'd be extremely grateful for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "it **seems** that Elixir recompiles" your deps?

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you make a new project?

Comment: @smathy i meant that my project recompiles every time i run a command related to "mix"

Comment: @AdamMillerchip no

Comment: are you running inside docker? It could be you are not using a volume for `_build`, so it needs to build every time.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip no, i am not working inside docker. just locally on my machine. However when i develop my project in docker, i get no problems with compilation.

Comment: I can't imagine how, but sounds like something funky with your `_build` directory, try deleting it and recompiling the whole project?

Comment: posted my solution, but the reason for that behavior remains unknown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: i solved the issue by running mix clean then mix setup when starting to work on a project. I don’t know the reason or why it happened or how it gets fixed but it works for me